# Ember.js: let component observe value changes of store items

Tags: javascript, ember.js, components, store

I am just starting to use Ember and came across the following problem. I want to observe whether or not there has been a change of value of an item within my store. As far as I understand, that is what the @each directive is for. Unfortunately, this does not trigger the respective method in my component.

My code is structured as follows.
The current route returns a subset of my store and has an action that changes one of the items.

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {                                                                                                                 
        this.store.push('node', {id: 1, x: 40, y:40});
        this.store.push('node', {id: 3, x: 50, y:50});
        return this.store.findAll("node");
    },
    actions: {
        move: function(x, y) {
            this.store.findRecord('node', 1).then(
                function(v) {
                    v.set("x", x); v.set("y", y);
                });
        }
    }   
});
```

I pass the model via a template directive to my component.

```
{{node-comp data=model}}
```

Now, I want to get a notification within the component, when a value in the model changes (i.e. in my example the action 'move' was called). My current approach looks like the following:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    rerender: function() {
        console.log("rerender called");
    }.observes("data.@each")
};
```

I tried the 'data.[]' directive and 'data.@each.x' directive as well. But nothing led to the desired behaviour. Notice that the template of the component is notified, i.e., the list of the items of the model gets updates after a 'move' call.

---

My 'ember -v' output

> Future versions of Ember CLI will not support v4.2.0. Please update to Node 0.12 or io.js.
>   version: 1.13.8 Could not find watchman, falling back to NodeWatcher
>   for file system events. Visit
>   http://www.ember-cli.com/user-guide/#watchman for more info. node:
>   4.2.0 npm: 2.13.4 os: linux x64

Answer (score 0):

You could try using "hasDirtyAttributes" property. I'm not sure however if this applies when pushing {x: 1} like objects. Why not use *store.createRecord('node', {x: 1})* etc.

http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#property_hasDirtyAttributes

```
rerender: function() {
        console.log("rerender called");
    }.observes("data.@each.hasDirtyAttributes")
```

NB! this does not work for async relations

Btw this rerendering looks weird.

What does your component contains of ? It really looks odd rendering after model change, you can have direct bindings of model values in your component. 
    component/file.js

```
{{#each data as |node|}}
  {{node.x}} < changes when node changes
{{/each}}
```

Comment: My component contains d3 code. The overall objective is to change my d3 visualization when the model changes. I am still looking into whether or not ember is the correct framework to achieve this. Unfortunately, adding the hasDirtyAttributs flag does not help.

Comment: Ive got d3 in my project. Data can be binded directly - {{bar-chart 
        data=graphData.data 
        isLoaded=graphData.data
        noDataText=noData
    }}

Comment: Thanks, but I do not see how this helps me, since I try to assemble a component of atomic 'd3-elements'. Thus, I can not revert to a prebuild component.